# Calculating difference in minutes from two timestamps

Tags: java, unix-timestamp

I have two unix time stamps like

```
currentTimestamp=1213083655;
previousTimestamp=1213083715;
```

How do I calculate the number of minutes between these two timestamps. Or in other words difference in minutes between both these timestamps.

Currently what I am doing is

```
(previousTimestamp-currentTimestamp)%60
```

which is the right away to go because timestamps are time in seconds and doing this will return minutes . But only problem is that when the difference is multiple of 60 then the remainder is 0 and therefore the calculation gives a result of 0 minutes which is wrong. Like in the case of above numbers difference is 60 so result is 0. So what's the best way to do this?

Regards 
Ahmar

Comment: Is Java 8 or Joda an option?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Use division instead of modulo.**

`%` is the modulo command.  You're not getting the number of minutes.  You're getting the remaining number of seconds after calculating whole minutes.

`/` is the division command.  This is what you are looking for.

```
(previousTimestamp-currentTimestamp)/60
```

This is the command you want.

Comment: Thanks. Didn't know how I made that silly mistake :)

Comment: nice!! to geter hour constant `Math.ceil((previousTimestamp-currentTimestamp)/60)`

Answer (score 2):

You don't want a modulo, but a division. Let's say the difference is 150 seconds. You need to **divide** it by 60 to find the difference in minutes: `2.5`:

```
double differenceInMinutes = (currentTimestamp - previousTimestamp) / 60d;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [JodaTime](http://www.joda.org/) in your project for date/time operations. To find out the gap between two DateTime in minutes:

```
DateTime now = DateTime.now();
DateTime dateTime = now.plusMinutes(10);
Minutes minutes = Minutes.minutesBetween(now, dateTime);
System.out.println(minutes.getMinutes());
```

If you use Maven, you can add JodaTime adding following dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
    <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
    <version>2.3</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

Why do you use a %?

`%` gives you module,that not what you're looking for.

`/` is what you have to use. A simple division.

Answer (score 0):

The [answer by Erhan Bagdemir](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21063064/642706) is correct.

Here is his idea using the [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) library, but adapted to literally solve the problem with values given by the question.

Using Joda-Time 2.3 and Java 7.

```java
// © 2013 Basil Bourque. This source code may be used freely forever by anyone taking full responsibility for doing so.
// import org.joda.time.*;

// We do not need time zones if our only goal is to count minutes. But realistically we are probably doing other work as well.
// Better to specify a time zone explicitly rather than rely on default.
// Time Zone list… http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/timezones.html  (not quite up-to-date, read page for details)
DateTimeZone timeZone = DateTimeZone.forID( "Europe/Paris" );

// Convert Unix time (seconds since epoch of 1970) to Joda-Time DateTime count of milliseconds since same epoch.
// Note the use of the 'long' type rather than the usual 'int', a common error when working with millisecond counts since epoch.
// Notice the hard-coded "L" on the numbers.
long start = ( 1213083655L * 1000L );
long stop = ( 1213083715 * 1000L );

DateTime dateTimeStart = new DateTime( start, timeZone );
DateTime dateTimeStop = new DateTime( stop, timeZone );

int minutesElapsed = Minutes.minutesBetween( dateTimeStart, dateTimeStop ).getMinutes();
```

Dump to console…

```java
System.out.println( "dateTimeStart: " + dateTimeStart );
System.out.println( "dateTimeStop: " + dateTimeStop );
System.out.println( "minutesElapsed: " + minutesElapsed );
```

When run…

```
dateTimeStart: 2008-06-10T09:40:55.000+02:00
dateTimeStop: 2008-06-10T09:41:55.000+02:00
minutesElapsed: 1
```